# Making multiple objects from user input

Tags: python

This is my current code:

```
class gym():
    def __init__(self,gymname):
        self.gymname=gymname
        self.memlist=[]
    def regMem(self,obj):
        if obj.ageMember()==True:
           self.memlist.append(obj)
           return True, "mem in!!!"
    def printMem(self):
        for n in self.memlist:
            print(n)





class gymMember():
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,age):
        self.fname=fname
        self.lname=lname
        self.age=age
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.fname)+str(self.lname)+str(self.age))

    def ageMember(self):
        if self.age>=18:
            return True
    def printMemlist(self):
        for n in self.memlist:
            print(n)

yes='y'
while yes=="y":
    g=gym("gym")
    name=input('enter f name')
    lname=input('enter l name')
    age=int(input('enter age'))
    n=gymMember(name,lname,age)
    print(g.regMem(n))
    g.printMem()
```

I'm trying to create multiple `gymMember` objects from the user input, but when I print the `memlist` out with all the gym members, only the most recent gym member appears, not the previous ones. My goal is to take the user input, create `gymMember` objects, and then store it in the container class `gym` with the list `memlist`:

```
enter f namejosh
enter l namelawmen
enter age23
(True, 'mem in!!!')
joshlawmen23
enter f nametory
enter l nameloome
enter age28
(True, 'mem in!!!')
toryloome28
enter f name
```

As you can see, only the most recent object shows when I print out the list. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had placed `g=gym("EzGym")` inside the while loop. At every iteration of the while loop, a new instance of `gym` class is created. When a new instance of `gym` is created, a new empty list is also created (see line 4: `self.memlist=[]`).

Therefore, you don't get the previously added `gymMember` instances when you do a `printMem()`.

You can fix this by shifting `g=gym('EzGym')` outside of the while loop.

```py
class gym():
    def __init__(self,gymname):
        self.gymname=gymname
        self.memlist=[]
    def regMem(self,obj):
        if obj.ageMember()==True:
           self.memlist.append(obj)
           return True, "mem in!!!"
    def printMem(self):
        for n in self.memlist:
            print(n)

class gymMember():
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,age):
        self.fname=fname
        self.lname=lname
        self.age=age
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.fname)+str(self.lname)+str(self.age))

    def ageMember(self):
        if self.age>=18:
            return True
    def printMemlist(self):
        for n in self.memlist:
            print(n)

yes='y'
g=gym("EzGym") # shift this line outside of the while loop
while yes=="y":
    name=input('enter f name')
    lname=input('enter l name')
    age=int(input('enter age'))
    n=gymMember(name,lname,age)
    print(g.regMem(n))
    g.printMem()
```